# An application of Kolmogorov $0$-$1$ law

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I need to approve or to disapprove the following statement :

if $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of independent random variables and identically distributed, and $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of real numbers such that 
$$\mathbb{P}(\limsup_n|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k-u_n|<+\infty)>0$$

then $\mathbb{P}(\limsup_n\frac{1}{n}|X_{2n+1}-X_{2n}|<+\infty)=1$

I know that by kolmogorov $0$-$1$ law (since $(\frac{1}{n}|X_{2n+1}-X_{2n}|)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of independent random variable), we have $\mathbb{P}(\limsup_n\frac{1}{n}|X_{2n+1}-X_{2n}|<+\infty)=0 \ \ or \ \ 1,$

So which value does it take?

Comment: Doesn't the existence of the $u_n$'s imply that the $X_n$'s are integrable, and thus that $\limsup_n \frac{1}{n}|X_n| = 0$ almost surely?

Comment: How can we prove that $X_n$ is integrable?

Comment: I thought $E[|X_n|] = +\infty$ implies $\limsup_n |\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k| = +\infty$ with probability 1. Is that false?

Comment: We can prove that there exists $\alpha \in \mathbb{R},$ such that $\limsup_n |\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k-u_n|=\alpha$ (Kolmogorov 0-1 law)

Comment: huh? is what I said true or false. that is, $(X_n)_n$ i.i.d. with $E[|X_n|] = +\infty$ implies $\limsup_n |\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k| = +\infty$ with prob 1

Comment: If that was true, then the problem is solved. In fact, using the above result, they told us to deduce that $X_n$ are integrable

Comment: @mathworker21: It's definitely true that if $E|X_n| = \infty$ then $\limsup_n \left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n X_k \right| = +\infty$ a.s.  See for instance Theorem 2.5.13 of Durrett's *PTE*.  What's less clear is that the limsup must still be infinite when $u_n$ is inserted.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'd be shocked if the proof of that result in Durrett wouldn't work with the $u_n$'s there.

Comment: @mathworker21: It certainly seems like it must be true, but I don't see how to adapt the proof.  Maybe you do?

Comment: @NateEldredge see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $P(\limsup_n \frac{1}{n}|X_{2n+1}-X_{2n}| < +\infty) < 1$. Then the $X_n$'s are not integrable. Let $\Delta_n = nu_n-(n-1)u_{n-1}$. Since $(\sum_{k=1}^n X_k -nu_n)-(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} X_k-(n-1)u_{n-1}) = X_n-\Delta_n$, it suffices to show $\limsup_n \frac{|X_n-\Delta_n|}{n} = +\infty$ almost surely. So it suffices to show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty Pr(|X_n-\Delta_n| \ge nk) = +\infty$ for all $k \ge 1$. Clearly this is true if $|\Delta_n|/n \to +\infty$ along a subsequence, as there is some $M$ with $Pr(|X_1| \le M) > 0$. So we may assume $|\Delta_n| \le Cn$ for each $n$, and then we're done, since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty Pr(|X_n| \ge (C+k)n) = +\infty$ (since $E[|X_1|] = +\infty$; see proof of first part of Theorem 2.5.13 in Durrett's book).

Comment: "and so $\limsup_{n \to \infty} |Y_n|/n = +\infty$ almost surely".  How do you prove this?   That's where I got stuck. I know how to do it if the $Y_n$ are iid and not integrable, but here they are not identically distributed.

Comment: @NateEldredge "but here they are not identically distributed" crap. thanks a lot. I'll keep thinking

Comment: @NateEldredge Ok, I think everything is correct now. Thanks again.

Comment: Nice, you did it!!

Comment: @mathex did u just delete a comment?

Comment: Yes, I did. It was concerning this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606510/l%c3%a9vys-metric-on-mathbbrd